# count <img> in div after drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 pieces of a image in a div `sortable1` which i have to drag and drop in another div `sortable2`to complete the image. After the image is dropped in another container it will stick to the previous image present in this container.http://jsfiddle.net/binit/JnYB9/

After every drop event i want to check whether all the 5 pieces are collected in 2nd div and if it is yes then change button text. Something like this.

```
if $('#sortable2').find('img').length == 5:
    document.getElementById('btn-start').text = "end";
```

But i don't know where to use this logic in my code or what should be the syntax

My code:

**javascript**

```
$(function() {

  $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "div"
  });

  $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "div",
  change: function( event, ui ) {
  var theID = ui.item.attr('id');
  ui.item.addClass(theID + '-style');
 }
 });


 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sortable1" class="well span10">   
<img id="north-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/north.png' %}" >    
<img id="south-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/south.png' %}" >    
<img id="east-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/east.png' %}" >    
<img id="west-img"   src="{% static 'images/demo/west.png' %}" >    
<img id="center-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/center.png' %}" >
</div>
<div id="sortable2"  class="well span7" style="height:800px">

  <a id="btn-start" href="/dashboard/save/" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed">Start</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stop` function of sortable evry time you sort the element from div with id `sortable1`.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JnYB9/2/)**

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
   if($('#sortable2').find('img').length==5)
   $('#btn-start').html("end");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a callback function on the sortable method like the following:

```
 $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
   connectWith: "div",
   stop: function() {
           // your logic goes here
   }
 });
```

You can also use the start callback.